# No component factory found for e. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, module, ionic3

I recently changed my Ionic 3 app to Lazy Loading pattern, but 'Im facing an issue when I build the app. When I run the app with *ionic-serve*, it works well, but when I build the app this message is shown when the splashscreen is hidden:

> No component factory found for e. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Any of the following scripts does show this message:

```
"ionic:build:test-local6": "ionic-app-scripts build android",
"ionic:build:test-local5": "ionic-app-scripts build android --aot",
"ionic:build:test-local4": "ionic cordova build android --aot --optimizejs",
"ionic:build:test-local2": "ionic-app-scripts android --prod --release",
"ionic:build:test-local3": "ionic cordova build android --prod",
"ionic:build:test-local": "ionic cordova build android --prod --release",
```

And this is my app-scripts version:
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.6",
}

This are my files:

**components.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

//Components
import * as Components from './components';

@NgModule({
entryComponents: [
    Components.Component1,
    Components.Component2,
    Components.Component3  
],
exports: [
     Components.Component1,
    Components.Component2,
    Components.Component3     
],
declarations: [
    Components.Component1,
    Components.Component2,
    Components.Component3     
],
imports: [
 IonicModule
],
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

**checklist.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import * as Pages from './../pages';
import { PipesModule } from '../../pipes/pipes.module';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module';


@NgModule({
exports: [
    Pages.ChecklistPage,
],
declarations: [
    Pages.ChecklistPage,
],
imports: [
    ComponentsModule,
    PipesModule,
  IonicPageModule.forChild(Pages.ChecklistPage),
],
  })
export class ChecklistPageModule {}
```

I've been searching in the internet for a solution to my issue but none works for me.

**UPDATE:**

I recently discovered that signing the apk makes this error happen. A non-signed apk always works.

This is my signing script:

```
#Create signed apk
/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/jarsigner.exe -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -storepass $password -keystore $keystorePath $releaseUnsignedPath $alias 

#Rename and verify signed apk
$zipalignPath -f -v 4 $releaseUnsignedPath $releaseSignedApk
```

Comment: I think you need to add `entryComponents` to`checklist.module.ts` `@NgModule` section

Comment: what's the full error message ? looks like AOT issue to me

Comment: @NitinP, but what do I put into those     entrycomponents? 

The components that the module is going to use?

Comment: I updated my question with important information

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It had nothing to do with module configurations. I missed to quote one page link on the app.

```
//this.navCtrl.setRoot(MenuPage); 
this.navCtrl.setRoot('MenuPage');
```

Thanks for the help anyway :D